# Enable Forms authentication on Virtual directory in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, forms-authentication, virtual-directory

I have an ASP.NET application in IIS 6.0 with the following structure. 
[image]

MyApplication is setup to run with Forms Authentication. I have a virtual directory called MyFiles that points to a shared network location containing some pdfs and docs.

The issue is that I am not able to secure this virtual directory with Forms Authentication. If I enable Anonymous access to the virtual directory, users are able to access all documents without login to the site. If I disable Anon access, they cannot access even after login. 
I tried setting up MyFolder as an application and keeping a web.config with location tag for the MyFiles virtual directory and denying anonymous. This did not work. 
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.